# Decode SSL and update state in NGXS

Tags: typescript, ssl, angular9, ngxs

I am learning NGXS and attempting to re-factor a material table that displays SSL certificate information for easy access. I have been able to successfully get the CertificateObject from our API but I am not sure how to go about decoding the certificate and updating the state.

Here is my state model:

```
export interface CertificateStateModel {
  certificate: CertificateObject;
  certificates: Certificate[];
  searchLimitedStateMessage: string;
  emptyCertificateMessage: string;
  searchTerm: any;
}

@State<CertificateStateModel>({
  name: "certificate",
  defaults: {
    certificate: null,
    certificates: [],
    searchLimitedStateMessage: SearchMessages.typeToSearch,
    emptyCertificateMessage: SearchMessages.typeToSearch,
    searchTerm: null,
  },
})
```

Here is the action where I get all certificates:

```
  @Action(CertificateAction.GetAllCertificates)
  getAllCertificates(
    ctx: StateContext<CertificateStateModel>,
    action: CertificateAction.GetAllCertificates
  ) {
    ctx.dispatch(new Busy(true));
    return this.svc.getAllCertificates().pipe(
      tap((certificate) => {
        ctx.patchState({
          certificate
        });
        ctx.dispatch(new Busy(true));
        console.log(certificate)
      },
      (error: any) => {
        ctx.dispatch([
          new DisplayMessage({type: "error", list: [ "Get All Certificates Error", error.error ]}),
          new Busy(false)
        ]);
      })
    );
  }
```

The certificate object looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "12345",
    "name": "accountName",
    "certificates": [
        {
            "publicCertificate": "EncodedCertHere",
            "id": "12345",
            "name": "atest"
        },
        {
            "publicCertificate": "EncodedCertHere",
            "id": "12345",
            "name": "btest"
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is how do I decode the certificate and set it to the certificates[] property on the state model?

For reference this is how I decoded the certificate before using matTableDataSource:

```
 this._integrationAccountService.getCertificates().subscribe(response => {
      this.data = [];
      if (response.certificates) {
          for (let entity of response.certificates) {

            const certPem = atob(entity.publicCertificate)
            const cert = pki.certificateFromPem(certPem)
            const fingerprint = forge.md.sha1.create().update(forge.asn1.toDer(forge.pki.certificateToAsn1(cert)).getBytes()).digest().toHex();
            const currentDate = new Date();
            const daysToExpire = cert.validity.notAfter.valueOf() - currentDate.valueOf();

              let row: CertificateRow = {
                  name: entity.name,
                  issueDate: cert.validity.notBefore,
                  expiryDate: cert.validity.notAfter,
                  fingerPrint: fingerprint,
                  serialNumber: cert.serialNumber,
                  daysToExpire: daysToExpire / 86400000,
              }
              this.data.push(row);
          }
      }

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: any, filter:string): boolean=> {
        //"data" here is the value of the "row"
        return data.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter);
      };
    })
  }
```

Any help to point me in the right direction would be great. I have been following the docs on the NGXS site but all the examples are quite simple and I am getting lost in the weeds.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just a nit pick, but try and use the action lifecycle instead of setting state for spinners/loaders etc... see: https://github.com/ngxs-labs/actions-executing
2. I would use the whatever code you are already using to decode the cert and then set it in your state, should be that easy.

```js
function decodeCert(cert: CertificateObject) {
 ... *decoding cert code*
}

////

@Action(CertificateAction.GetAllCertificates)
getAllCertificates(
  ctx: StateContext<CertificateStateModel>,
  action: CertificateAction.GetAllCertificates
) {
  // ctx.dispatch(new Busy(true)); <-- See Point 1
  return this.svc.getAllCertificates().pipe(
    tap((certificate) => {
      ctx.patchState({
        certificate: decodeCert(certificate), // <-- See Point 2
      });
      // ctx.dispatch(new Busy(true)); <-- See Point 1
      console.log(certificate)
    },
    (error: any) => {
      ctx.dispatch([
        new DisplayMessage({type: "error", list: [ "Get All Certificates Error", error.error ]}),
        // new Busy(false) <-- See Point 1
      ]);
    })
  );
}

@Selector([CertificateState])
getCerts(state: CertificateState){
  return ... get your data rows here...
}
```

The material table is pretty good at what it does, but you do have to jump through a couple of hoops to get it to work. Not sure what your view looks like, so I'm just going to wing it

`table-wrapper.ts`

```js
@Select(CertificateState.getCerts) data$: Observable<T>;
```

`table-wrapper.html`

```html
<app-table data="data$ | async"></app-table>
```

`table.html`

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
<!-- contents -->
</table>
```

`table.ts`

```js
// one way to set the incoming datasource
@Input() public set data(value: T) {
    this.dataSource.data = value;
}

// another way to set the incoming data source
@Input() data: T[];
ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.dataSource.data = this.data;
}
```

Comment: hello @Richard.Davenport! thank you for your help, I did not see your response yesterday. When I try to implement your solution I get two errors: "type void is not assignable to type 'CertificateObject'" and "Argument of type 'CertificateObject' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Certificate[]'."

Comment: The code is totally written on this page, not in an editor. I wouldn't have expected it to work. From the errors it sounds like a pretty simple types mistake. Just correct the types to match.